# Android resource linking failed when I tried to run my application

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to run my project but it showing an error, which is:

> C:\Users\kainat.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\280fc69a02ac6e58d90f0b7a9fe6bffe\material-1.5.0-alpha05\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-94: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_neutral1_1000 not found.

Showing the following file, cursor at line first under

```
en<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral0">@android:color/system_neutral1_1000</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral10">@android:color/system_neutral1_900</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral100">@android:color/system_neutral1_0</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral20">@android:color/system_neutral1_800</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral30">@android:color/system_neutral1_700</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral40">@android:color/system_neutral1_600</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral50">@android:color/system_neutral1_500</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral60">@android:color/system_neutral1_400</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral70">@android:color/system_neutral1_300</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral80">@android:color/system_neutral1_200</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral90">@android:color/system_neutral1_100</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral95">@android:color/system_neutral1_50</color>
   <color name="m3_ref_palette_dynamic_neutral99">@android:color/system_neutral1_10</color>ter
```

Using **SDK version 31** and followning dependency:

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05'
```

what should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Try to Downgrade from `material:1.5.0-alpha05` to `material:1.5.0-alpha02`

Comment: showing this error now : Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Comment: Actually its showing 20 errors like this(mentioned in the question) in the same file...!

Comment: @BintEHawa, Have you got any solution for this?